# How to pivot and merge to avoid the NULL cells?

Tags: t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2019

Sample table data:

```
SELECT [id],[date],[agent],[sales]
  FROM [AgentSales]

id  date                    agent   sales
1   2021-01-02 00:00:00.000 Agent A 10
2   2021-01-03 00:00:00.000 Agent A 2
3   2021-01-04 00:00:00.000 Agent B 22
4   2021-01-06 00:00:00.000 Agent B 5
5   2021-02-05 00:00:00.000 Agent A 1
6   2021-02-06 00:00:00.000 Agent B 33
7   2021-03-06 00:00:00.000 Agent A 11
8   2021-03-06 00:00:00.000 Agent B 3
```

Group by YearMonth, Agent:

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR) YRMON, AGENT, SUM(SALES) SALES
  FROM AgentSales
  GROUP BY  CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR), AGENT
  ORDER BY 1

YRMON   AGENT   SALES
2021 1  Agent A 12
2021 1  Agent B 27
2021 2  Agent A 1
2021 2  Agent B 33
2021 3  Agent A 11
2021 3  Agent B 3
```

PIVOT:

```
  SELECT CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR) YRMON, [AGENT A], [AGENT B]
  FROM AgentSales
  PIVOT (SUM(SALES) FOR AGENT IN ([AGENT A], [AGENT B])) AS PIVOTTABLE

YRMON   AGENT A AGENT B
2021 1  10      NULL
2021 1  2       NULL
2021 1  NULL    22
2021 1  NULL    5
2021 2  1       NULL
2021 2  NULL    33
2021 3  11      NULL
2021 3  NULL    3
```

I want to have the actual value in place of the NULLs. So effectively there should be only 2 rows for each YearMon. How to do this?

Expected result:

```
  YRMON   AGENT A AGENT B
  2021 1  12      27
  2021 2  1       33
  2021 3  11      3
```

Comment: Can you please describe what is your expected result according to the sample data

Comment: Added expected result to question

Comment: Check how your expected result looks like - all in one line with not tabular structure - it is not readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like simple conditional aggregation should do the trick.

```sql
SELECT
  FORMAT(EOMONTH([DATE]), 'yyyy MM') YRMON,
  SUM(CASE WHEN AGENT = 'AGENT B' THEN SALES END) [AGENT B],
  SUM(CASE WHEN AGENT = 'AGENT A' THEN SALES END) [AGENT A]
FROM AgentSales
GROUP BY EOMONTH([DATE])
ORDER BY EOMONTH([DATE]);
```

Or if you want each one on a separate row, you can add in a row-number and group on that

```sql
SELECT
  FORMAT(EOMONTH([DATE]), 'yyyy MM') YRMON,
  SUM(CASE WHEN AGENT = 'AGENT B' THEN SALES END) [AGENT B],
  SUM(CASE WHEN AGENT = 'AGENT A' THEN SALES END) [AGENT A]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EOMONTH([DATE]), AGENT ORDER BY [DATE])
    FROM AgentSales
) sales
GROUP BY EOMONTH([DATE]), rn
ORDER BY EOMONTH([DATE]), rn;
```

> Grouping by `EOMONTH` is more performant than grouping by a string

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8290e4ae92a9dd8b883762b1c448ab5e)

Comment: How about this - `;with cte as (SELECT CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR) YRMON, AGENT, SUM(SALES) SALES
  FROM AgentSales
  GROUP BY  CAST(YEAR([DATE]) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CAST(MONTH([DATE]) AS VARCHAR), AGENT
)
SELECT YRMON, [AGENT A], [AGENT B]
  FROM cte
  PIVOT (SUM(SALES) FOR AGENT IN ([AGENT A], [AGENT B])) AS PIVOTTABLE`

Comment: Conditional aggregation is much easier to work with than `PIVOT`